# shared folder doesn't contain data

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I created a volume with

```
docker volume create --name mydata
```

Now and want to use this volume as a shared folder for two container.
So my docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
app1:
  volume:
    - mydata:/some/folder

app2:
  volume:
    - mydata:/another/folder
```

I can see that `app1` writes files into `/some/folder` but when I look into `app2` then `/another/folder` is empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suggest you run a docker inspect on both your containers to achieve their exact mount points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, use docker-compose format version 2.
Then specify that you're using an externally created volume like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  app1:
    volume:
      - mydata:/some/folder

  app2:
    volume:
      - mydata:/another/folder

volumes:
  mydata:
    external:
      name: mydata
```